# What does correlated data mean and how can I visualize it with scatterplot?

Tags: r, machine-learning, correlation

I'm playing around with the Abalone dataset in R and following along with [this article](http://scg.sdsu.edu/linear-regression-in-r-abalone-dataset/).

The dataset has 8 variables that are taken into account to predict the number of `rings`. To find the pairwise correlation, the blog post does this:

```
as.matrix(cor(na.omit(abalone[,-1])))
```

and comes to conclusion that the data is heavily correlated. My question is how do they come to this conclusion? What information should I be looking for to come to this conclusion?

Here is the code

```
> aburl = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data'
> abnames = c('sex','length','diameter','height','weight.w','weight.s','weight.v','weight.sh','rings')
> abalone = read.table(aburl, header = F , sep = ',', col.names = abnames)
> as.matrix(cor(na.omit(abalone[,-1])))

             length  diameter    height  weight.w  weight.s  weight.v weight.sh     rings
length    1.0000000 0.9868116 0.8275536 0.9252612 0.8979137 0.9030177 0.8977056 0.5567196
diameter  0.9868116 1.0000000 0.8336837 0.9254521 0.8931625 0.8997244 0.9053298 0.5746599
height    0.8275536 0.8336837 1.0000000 0.8192208 0.7749723 0.7983193 0.8173380 0.5574673
weight.w  0.9252612 0.9254521 0.8192208 1.0000000 0.9694055 0.9663751 0.9553554 0.5403897
weight.s  0.8979137 0.8931625 0.7749723 0.9694055 1.0000000 0.9319613 0.8826171 0.4208837
weight.v  0.9030177 0.8997244 0.7983193 0.9663751 0.9319613 1.0000000 0.9076563 0.5038192
weight.sh 0.8977056 0.9053298 0.8173380 0.9553554 0.8826171 0.9076563 1.0000000 0.6275740
rings     0.5567196 0.5746599 0.5574673 0.5403897 0.4208837 0.5038192 0.6275740 1.0000000
> pairs(abalone[,-1]
```

[image]

**Questions**

- What is the problem when the data is heavily correlated?
- How can one come to conclusion that the data is heavily correlated by looking at the matrix or by looking at the scatterplot? Is it because the scatterplot shows linear lines in almost every row-column?

Comment: "Heavily correlated" because meany correlations are high (near their maximum value). The diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) may be of some use in seeing the relationship between the 'nearly linear' plots and the correlation values.

Comment: See also [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) for more discussion of what the correlations actually are.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [plotcorr function](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ellipse/html/plotcorr.html). I find it to be a very clear way to visualize correlations.

It will give you a plot much like the following (but slightly different as I generated this plot with Python, and not R)

[image: Correlation matrix plotted with plotcorr clone in Python]

The diagonal of this matrix shows how correlated each variable is with itself, which by definition will be *p=1*. Looking at the off-diagonal ellipses shows the correlation between parameters. It is clear that the data is heavily correlated since most of them have correlation values greater than *0.5*. See the [article suggested by Glen_b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) for details on how the values are calculated. *p=0* is same as the random case (no correlation).

In answer to your first question, one problem with correlated data is that it is uninformative. In other words, a model which trained on just say *length*, will perform pretty much as well as a model which trained on all of the parameters. But the second model is much more likely to over-train since it will have much more freedom to fit its model parameters to the data.